# Apache 2 vhost with two names (host alias?)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have an Apache server with vhosts configured. I want one of my vhosts to answer to two names, lalala.domain.com and abc123.domain.com.

I could define two vhosts that are exactly the same except or the ServerName attribute in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled but that seems silly to me. Is there I way I can define the vhost once and then add some sort of alias name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias) is the name of the directive you're looking for.

Comment: Oh man, that was so easy. I have been searching the web trying to find the directive name, how on earth did I not find it! Doh! :D

Comment: you must ask the right question. yours was far from it, at least for search engines :)